# How to check if dynamically created div's exist using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am creating these div's dynamically when user adds products to compare.

```
//code in jquery
var innerdiv='<div id="innerdiv'+value.code+'"'+'>'+value.name+'<img src="'+value.thumbnail+'"/></div>';
$('#compare-pane').append(innerdiv);
```

How do I check dynamically if the compare pane is empty or it has inner divs?

I have to hide a button if compare-pane is empty.

The inner div `id` is dynamically generated  (e.g `innerdiv166104`).

How do I check if any inner div exists? I cannot use empty check as there are another elements inside compare-pane too which are required.

I cannot fetch the inner div `id's` as they will be coming dynamically as per users selection.

Comment: Probably best to use a class on that div, so you don't have to select by *part* of an ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the "starts with" selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to see if you have any `div` elements matching a pattern in the `id`:

```
if ($('#compare-pane div[id^="innerdiv"]').length > 0) {
    // inner divs exist
}
```